# react-google-maps InfoBox not working with react-datepicker

Tags: reactjs, react-google-maps, react-datepicker

So, the main problem is that the component InfoBox won't allow "onChange" handlers (I presume). I need that specific one because the 3rd party component (react-datepicker) uses the "onChange" handler to set the date.

Digging through the official documentation, I've found this for the setting property "enableEventPropagation":

> Propagate mousedown, mousemove, mouseover, mouseout, mouseup, click,
>   dblclick, touchstart, touchend, touchmove, and contextmenu events in
>   the InfoBox (default is false to mimic the behavior of a
>   google.maps.InfoWindow). Set this property to true if the InfoBox is
>   being used as a map label.

That's why I think it may be impossible to do it with the given date-picker, but I might be mistaken.

I've also tried setting the CSS so the date-picker component is positioned absolute to the relative parent DIV containing both the InfoBox and the date-picker, but for some reason, I cannot seem to wrap the InfoBox with the parent DIV no matter what I do. 
The thought process behind this is that my react-datepicker component is not really a part of InfoBox (so the "onChange" handler will work - because it works everywhere else in the app)

Any thoughts?
Thanks a million!

P.S.

Setting "enableEventPropagation" to false is a default behaviour and will lead to InfoBox acting like a "read-only" label that won't allow clicks (inside its contents).